# Possible to change tooltip size after using tooltip-append-to-body

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

My tooltip goes hidden, so I applied tooltip-append-to-body="true", that problem get solved but due to that my tooltip size got bigger and now If I override tooltip-inner css by giving max-width, due to I append the tooltip to the body css is not working

I've already tried 
max-width, 
width, 
word-wrap css

```
<li class="dropdown-css"
    ng-click="onclickfuntion($event)">
    <span class="export-pdf"
          uib-tooltip="Click here to export the widget asPDF"
          tooltip-placement="top"
          tooltip-append-to-body="true">
          Export to PDF
     </span>
</li>
```

I want a break between "the  widget as PDF". By default it's taking 200 px I want 150px size

Comment: Try adding `container: 'body' ` inside the `span` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I've read official documentation and find out we can add css specifically to tooltip through tooltip-class="yourDefineCssName".So, decrease size of tooltip and automatically your text will go into next line.

```
<li class="dropdown-css"
    ng-click="onclickfuntion($event)">
    <span class="export-pdf"
          uib-tooltip="Click here to export the widget asPDF"
          tooltip-placement="top"
          tooltip-append-to-body="true"
          tooltip-class="yourDefineCssName">
          Export to PDF
 </span>
```

```
And css will be 

.yourDefineCssName{
max-width: 150px !important;
}
```